# Problem Time Series Forecasting from Azure ML to Power Bi Desktop

Tags: azure, machine-learning, powerbi-desktop, azure-machine-learning-service

i have created a model from azure machine learning with "Automated ML", its a time series forecasting model. I configured that model to predict from now to 12 months. Then i created a endpoint to connect to my power bi desktop. I tested the endpoint and it worked fine with more than 100 rows (you are gonna understand why i say 100 rows later). (The endpoint parameters are the date and customer_id)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0svJ.png)

But when i do try to do it in power query with a table from a sql query i got this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNKcx.png)

The weird thing is that it only happens when i bring more than 100 rows from the sql query because when i bring less than 100 rows or exactly 100 rows it works perfect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqa9v.png)

Please, help me! :c

I need to predict all of my clients (they are more than 1000 rows)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The error clearly states that there is connection missing between the ML portal and power BI report. The implementation needs to have the prediction context to be available for the Power BI report. Connection was established and the data must be processed perfectly for analysis from the prediction output.

There is no limitation of number of rows from ML model results to the Power BI desktop.

For example, consider time series data of diabetics and there are large numbers of rows and there is no restriction from model to power BI as mentioned in the below image.

[image]

To get the predictions, click on the symbol mentioned in the image.

[image]

Then we will get the column with prediction results.

[image]

There is no restriction on the number of rows. And the connection must be established perfectly.

Comment: There is connection because its work but when i limit the input data. I think the problem is how the data is sent to machine learning studio when i put data from december of 2022 to december of 2023